# XML parser error: entity not defined in all browsers

Tags: xml, parsing, entity

I wrote a simple XML file and a DTD file including an entity, but when I want to check it in my browsers I get the message:

XML parser error: entity not defined.
Address: file:///Users/Mike/Documents/fb.xml
Row 8, column 22

I tried to find an answer, most refer to an add-on problem with Firefox. I, however, get this message on Mac OS X 10.7 with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and on Windows 7 with Firefox and Chrome. IE does nothing. (Opera on my Mac doesn't give me a message, but it doesn't show the text replacement either.)

Here are my files.
DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT example (some_list) >
<!ELEMENT some_list (item+)>
<!ELEMENT item (element1, element2)>
<!ELEMENT element1 (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT element2 (#PCDATA) >
<!ENTITY entity1 "1234567890" >
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE some_list SYSTEM "Allgemeine_Entities.dtd">
<some_list>
    <item>
        <element1>Some Text</element1>
        <element2>more Text and &entity1;</element2>
    </item>
</some_list>
```

As the problem appears in all my browsers, I assume it is not a browser specific problem.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent browsers will mostly not [load external DTDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28XML%29#Schema_technologies)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I got to hear from other sources now, too. Using an internal DTD works fine, external DTDs cause problems.